# Express Module - Export Object to Main Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I am struggling with passing an object in Express from a module to my application. The application is simple. I take input from a form, test the string and then return either null or an object. However, I have tried different approaches and my object still comes back undefined. Looking for the most efficient way to pass an object from a module into my application.

Here is the code in my app.js

```js
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();
var checkString = require('./checkString.js');

//Test Server Connection
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

//Set Use
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(router);

//Set Routes
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views/pages'));


//GET Method
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  //Renders EJS Template and variables

  res.render('index');
});


//Receive User Input from Form
//Post Request
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

  //Check Form Input Results
  var formInput = req.body.inputText;
  var ReqMethod = req.method;
  console.log(`Method: ${ReqMethod}`);
  console.log(`Body: ${formInput}`);

  //Assign form data to a variable after calling a function
  checkString.dateResponse(formInput);


  //res.json(checkString.timeStamp);
  res.end();
});
```

Here is the code for my module ('checkString.js')

```js
//var exports = module.exports {};

var moment = require('moment');

//Create TimeStamp Object to Export to Server.js
exports.timeStamp = function(unix, natural) {
  this.unix = unix;
  this.natural = natural;
}

//Function Working in Chrome Console

exports.dateResponse = function(data) {


  //Check The Date
  if (isNaN(data)) {

    return null

  } else {

    return data;

  }


  //Update timeStamp object with time/date

  if (data !== null) {

    var unix = moment(x).unix();

    var natural = moment(x).format('MMM Do, YYYY');

    return timeStamp(unix, natural);

  } else {

    return null
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few issues with your code, but most important I think is that you just return data and do nothing with it. So

```
console.log(checkString.dateResponse(formInput));
```

should return formInput if its not NaN. Nothing more, cause it cannot go any further cause of return. Moreover "isNaN" is not the best way to check if number is NaN (it fails in many non number cases). Best way to check if nan is nan is to compare if

```
a !== a
```

cause only NaN not equals itself. (Of course I'm assumming the primitives, cause function results can be not equal)

Thirdly you'r code could be more tidy if you move checking to the top

```
if(isNan(data) || data === null) {
     return null
}
```

You will avoid unnecessary intendation. You could also move logical operators to variables and state only variable inside of if. (But sometimes is just overkill)

```
 const isNaN = data !== data;
 const isNull = data === null || data === undefined;
 const isNall = isNaN || isNull
 if (isNall) {
   return null
 }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. I made those tweaks to my code. The reason I am using the console.log() is to check the outputs from the object. However, I am still getting a blank object. My confusion is related to passing the timeStamp object. I keep getting a blank object on my return. No sure if the problem resides in the request method or in the module to check the string.

Comment: evertyhing looks OK besides what I've said. Maybe its your formInput value? I know that its weak way to check - but I'd put your module inside function and check if there's result. But I'm pretty sure everythings fine. You can also use debugger; (see node.js debugger) so you'll assign breakpoints and see if code goes through and its state.

Comment: hmm..I am still struggling with returning an object from the function. Will have to keep searching. Thanks for your insight. That helped clean up my code